# How can I implement Polar area charts with Chart.js and Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

Now,I would like to implement a polar area chart like following picture with Chart.js and Canvas.

How should I do to implement it?

[image]

So far,I tried the following code but it does not work.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
  <style media="screen" type="text/css">#container{width:100%;height:100%;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;position:absolute;}</style>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        const canvas = document.getElementById('chart')
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        const gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(75, 50, 5, 90, 60, 100)
        const [ w , h ] = [ canvas.clientWidth , canvas.clientHeight ];
        gradient.addColorStop(0.0 , 'rgb(255,0,0)');
        gradient.addColorStop(0.5 , 'rgb(0,255,0)');

        const data = {
          backgroundColor: [gradient,gradient,gradient,gradient,gradient],
          labels: ['First label', 'Second label', 'Third label', 'Fourth label', 'Fifth label'],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: 'First dataset',
              backgroundColor: gradient,
              data: [50, 20, 40, 50, 22]
            }
          ]
        };

        const options = {
          tooltips: {
            mode: 'label'
          },

        };

        const myRadarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'polarArea',
          data,
          options
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="chart" width="${width}" height="${width}" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
  <style media="screen" type="text/css">#container{width:100%;height:100%;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;position:absolute;}</style>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        const canvas = document.getElementById('chart')
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        const [ w , h ] = [ canvas.clientWidth , canvas.clientHeight ];
        const r = 300;
        const gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(w, h*1.2, 0, w, h, r * 0.6);
        gradient.addColorStop(0.0 , 'rgb(255,0,0)');
        gradient.addColorStop(1 , 'rgb(0,255,0)');

        const data = {
          backgroundColor: [gradient,gradient,gradient,gradient,gradient],
          labels: ['First label', 'Second label', 'Third label', 'Fourth label', 'Fifth label'],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: 'First dataset',
              backgroundColor: gradient,
              data: [50, 20, 40, 50, 22]
            }
          ]
        };

        const options = {
          tooltips: {
            mode: 'label'
          },

        };

        const myRadarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'polarArea',
          data,
          options
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="chart" width="${width}" height="${width}" />
</body>
</html>
```

The code is good! It's only a case of using the canvas width, height and radius of the chart's largest circle to [position the gradient correctly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createRadialGradient#parameters). Minor adjustments can also be made if the final chart position in the canvas shifts (e.g. where a different canvas aspect ratio is used).

From there, it is simple to create a new gradient in the same way for each combination of colours you wish to use.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
When I run your code and watch that chart in full page,it seems it does not work